# MySQL Error querying from PHP: IF EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, exists

I have this PHP Code with Query to mysql database:

```
$query2 = "IF( EXISTS (SELECT * FROM shipcargo WHERE shipid='$shipid' AND item='$item' AND price='$price')) 
    BEGIN
    UPDATE shipcargo SET amount = amount+'$amount' WHERE shipid='$shipid' AND item='$item' AND price='$price'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO shipcargo (shipid, item, amount, price) VALUES('$shipid', '$item', '$amount', '$price')
    END";
    mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
```

The Error Returned is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF( EXISTS (SELECT * FROM shipcargo WHERE shipid='11' AND item='WheatBastard' AN' at line 1

Comment: PHP does not trigger SQL errors. You have to check what exactly `$query2` contains and see if it's valid SQL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syntax is wrong! Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM
```

Rather than

```
IF (EXISTS ( SELECT
```

You don't need a bracket with the IF statement